# React Nextjs: Module parse failed:You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am trying to load a pdf file

```
import placeholder from "../assets/pdf/placeholder.pdf"
```

And every time the server reloads I get this error:
*
error - ./assets/pdf/placeholder.pdf
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using **Webpack4**, it appears you want the `raw-loader`

https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/

```
{
  test: /\.pdf$/i,
  use: 'raw-loader',
}
```

If you are using **Webpack5**, the new Asset Modules are available:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

(raw-loader replacement)

```
{
  test: /\.pdf$/i
  type: 'asset/source'
}
```

(file-loader replacement)

```
{
  test: /\.pdf$/i
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    filename: `[name][ext]`
  }
}
```