# Webpack Cannot load pdf file: Module parse failed You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, pdf, webpack, next.js

I am new to webpack. Recently, I wanted to find a way to view pdfs in one of my projects. I have found out a library called "react-pdf" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) and decided to experiment with it. When using it in a test react project (npx create-react-app), everything worked fine, but when I to introduced it to the real project, using Nextjs, things went wrong.

```
import placeholder from "../src/placeholder.pdf""
```

Every time the server reloads I get this error:
*
error - ./assets/pdf/placeholder.pdf
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)*

This is the webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.pdf$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: `[name][ext]`
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Next.js, [custom webpack configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) is setup in `next.config.js`. Can you share your Next.js config file?

Comment: You already asked this question the other day and I answered it. You have configured this to be a resource asset, but I'm pretty sure you want a `type: 'asset/source'` so it loads the raw contents of the PDF.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805853/react-nextjs-module-parse-failedyou-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-t/70806393#70806393

Comment: `type: 'asset/source` did not work, the problem was that webpack was not even installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) =>
    {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.pdf$/i,
            type: 'asset/source'
        })

        return config
    },
}
```

Comment: Is this a complete answer to your question, or additional information that should be in the question instead?

Comment: this is the full answer